# how to process image with opencv in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I want to use edge detection algorithms from opencv library.
Here is a piece of python code:

```
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *

img = cvLoadImage ('xxx.jpg')
cvNamedWindow ('img')
cvShowImage ('img', img)
cvWaitKey ()

canny = cvCreateImage (cvSize (img.width, img.height), 8, 3)
cvCanny (img, canny, 50, 200)

harris = cvCreateImage (cvSize (img.width, img.height), 8, 3)
cvCornerHarris (img, harris, 5, 5, 0.1)
```

Loading and showing image works fine, but canny and harris transformations fail.
`cvCanny` fails with:

```
RuntimeError:  openCV Error:
    Status=Unsupported format or combination of formats
    function name=cvCanny
    error message=
    file_name=cv/cvcanny.cpp
    line=72
```

and `cvCornerHarris` fails with this error:

```
RuntimeError:  openCV Error:
    Status=Assertion failed
    function name=cvCornerHarris
    error message=src.size() == dst.size() && dst.type() == CV_32FC1
    file_name=cv/cvcorner.cpp
    line=370
```

From this messages I can infer that loaded image has invalid format. But I don't understand how to convert it.
Here are values of some `img` fields:

```
img.type = 1111638032
img.nChannels = 3
img.depth = 8
```

Comment: what version of the API are you using? your code seems to be consistant with the old API and could be confusing for new users: you should use "import cv" and such. I'll be happy to translate your code if you wish

Comment: @meduz, it is python-opencv_2.0.0-3ubuntu2. I installed it from Ubuntu 10.04 repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's fixed code.  See comments inline.  Long story short: your data types were wrong.  Read the [API](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/index.html).

```
try:
    from opencv.cv import *
    from opencv.highgui import *
except:
    #
    # Different OpenCV installs name their packages differently.
    #
    from cv import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    #
    # 1 = Force the image to be loaded as RGB
    #
    img = LoadImage (sys.argv[1], 1)
    NamedWindow ('img')
    ShowImage ('img', img)
    WaitKey ()

    #
    # Canny and Harris expect grayscale  (8-bit) input.
    # Convert the image to grayscale.  This is a two-step process:
    #   1.  Convert to 3-channel YCbCr image
    #   2.  Throw away the chroma (Cb, Cr) and keep the luma (Y)
    #
    yuv = CreateImage(GetSize(img), 8, 3)
    gray = CreateImage(GetSize(img), 8, 1)
    CvtColor(img, yuv, CV_BGR2YCrCb)
    Split(yuv, gray, None, None, None)

    canny = CreateImage(GetSize(img), 8, 1)
    Canny(gray, canny, 50, 200)
    NamedWindow ('canny')
    ShowImage ('canny', canny)
    WaitKey()

    #
    # The Harris output must be 32-bit float.
    #
    harris = CreateImage (GetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    CornerHarris(gray, harris, 5, 5, 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I read the API but it is not obvious which image format each transformation expects.

Comment: btw, both imports (`openhighgu` and `cv`) does not work on my ubuntu 10.04

Comment: If they didn't work, how did you run the code?  That would generally mean the Python wrappers for OpenCV are not installed.

Comment: they work like in my source, i.e. everything is imported with `cv` prefix

Comment: Oh, sorry.  That means there is a typo in my code -- I must've changed it when I was trying to make it work on my system.  I'll go edit it now.

Answer (score 8):

For other folks interested in the same type of problem I recommend checking out http://simplecv.org

Here is a bit of code I wrote that does line detection on an image acquired from a webcam.  It will even display the image over http. [image: beard detection]

```
import SimpleCV
import time

c = SimpleCV.Camera(1)
js = SimpleCV.JpegStreamer() 

while(1):
  img = c.getImage()
  img = img.smooth()
  lines = img.findLines(threshold=25,minlinelength=20,maxlinegap=20)
  [line.draw(color=(255,0,0)) for line in lines]
  #find the avg length of the lines
  sum = 0
  for line in lines:
      sum = line.length() + sum
  if sum:
      print sum / len(lines)
  else:
      print "No lines found!"
  img.save(js.framebuffer)
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Check out the project I made this for at http://labs.radiantmachines.com/beard/ It will detect how long your neck beard is :)

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. +++1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an image to grayscale in a single step instead of two:

```
gray = cv.CreateMat(img.height, img.width, cv.CV_8UC1)
cv.CvtColor(img, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
```