# efficient data structure for storing multiple images in python

Tags: python, variables, opencv, data-structures, storage

What would be a good way to store multiple images loaded using OpenCV in Python? In C++ it can be simply done using vector of Mat's.

How to do it in Python? Buil in arrays AFAIK are suitable only for simple data. Should I use some vector or something like that library?

Comment: a C++ vector and a python list are very very similar.

Comment: @BostonJohn: A C++ vector stores copies of its elements, a Python list stores references.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. What would be wrong with making a user specified object Image like this:

```
from opencv.cv import *
class Image:
    def __init__(self, file):
        image = cvLoadImage (file)
        # whatever else you may need to store or do


list = []
someImg = Image("C:/somefile.png")
list.append(someImg)
```

and then storing those in a list?
That's how I would do it in your situation, but I may be mis-interpreting the specifics of your question.

Edit: I also haven't really used OpenCV in python, so I'm not sure how the imports and image creation works, but it appears to be something like this.  Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002922/how-to-process-image-with-opencv-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650568/how-do-i-create-an-opencv-image-from-a-pil-image)

Also, the `numpy.ndarray` is a good one, since you seem to be referring to using a vector (here python list) of matrices (here numpy.ndarrays), which you may be more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

When I am working with OpenCV my choice is to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) ndarrays.  It is fast and easy convert back and forth between numpy arrays and OpenCV Image/Matrix classes, only a thin wrapper is needed, and numpy provides you with a ton of numerical tricks and libraries to use.

That being said, there would be nothing wrong with simply using lists of cv's native iplimage class (a structure inherited from intel image processing library).